# Git svn - Clone trunk while maintaining path

Tags: git, git-svn

I am running a local git repository and want to clone the remote SVN trunk. This works fine but the trunk/ part of the folder is left off. The remote repository is too large to just clone or fetch the whole thing with branches etc.

I need the path correct for our code review tool.

How can I do a git-svn that only clones a certain trunk/branch but keeps the path intact?

```
/trunk/folders
/branch/folders
```

Selecting the Trunk option has the local path of

folders

I need it to be

trunk/folders

Comment: How do you initialize git-svn repository now?

Comment: git svn init svn://path/trunk then git svn fetch -rxxxx since the repository is so big. Also tried using the gui with trunk/branch selected etc.

Comment: anyway Im not sure what the question is all about but probably you want to look into .git/config file and get some idea how to add extra svn clones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have been doing this is

```
svn init -T svn://path/to/trunk
svn git fetch
```

I have also been using the -r option to git fetch to avoid fetching history from all eternity. You can also add back in branches/tags in to .git/config, this is documented in the git-svn manpage.

Answer (score 0):

1. (Not sure about this but it's the easiest solution)
   You could just move the directory folders into a new folder trunk. Git won't mind and other tools will find the path you want.
2. You could do a `git svn init svn://path/trunk trunk`
3. Also check the `--ignore-patch` option of  `git svn fetch`